# How to properly position animated numbers in a stacked css flexbox?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display animated text in a css flexbox. It should be displayed "30,538+" on first line and "Leggs Broken" on second line (dummy text). Both should be stacked in the center of the page (I have other text above and below it). The numbers are animated on hover with just CSS.

```css
.legg-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.legg-desc {
  color: #ae95da;
  padding-top: 50px;
  align-items: center;
}


/* number animation */

.legg body {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.legg ul {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  margin-top: 225px;
}

.legg ul li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #ae95da;
  float: left;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  transition: 0.9s;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.legg ul:hover li {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

.legg ul:hover li:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.9s;
}
```

```html
<div class="legg-section">
  <h1 class="legg">
    <ul>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>0</li>
      <li>,</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>+</li>
      <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </ul>
  </h1>
  <h2 class="legg-desc">Leggs Broken</h2>
</div>
```

The first problem I am having is that the numbers jump up or down when the screen is resized. I am having trouble pinning it to a specific spot on the page. Second thing is to have it expand and shrink properly on screen size (a little buggy now).

I spent many hours trying to fix and troubleshoot this but nothing worked. Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What kind of animation do you want?

Comment: You can use the performance monitor on chrome dev tools to look at the parts of your page that cause janky issues. Also if you're going to use any transitions then define the transtions you're going to use e.g. transition: transform 0.9s; as opposed to transition: 0.9s;. As a last resort if you are still having issues you can use the 'will-change' css property that lets the browser optimise your page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to keep the style as much the same as possible. Basically, any positioning and floating has been removed. The rest is pretty straightforward.

```css
.legg-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.legg-desc {
  color: #ae95da;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

ul li {
  color: #ae95da;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  transition: 0.9s;
  font-weight: 400;
}

/* number animation */

ul:hover li {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

ul:hover li:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.9s;
}
```

```html
<div class="legg-section">
  <ul>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>0</li>
    <li>,</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>+</li>
  </ul>
  <h2 class="legg-desc">Leggs Broken</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Beat me to it!!

Comment: Thank you so much, Gerard! You are a life saver! It works perfectly across multiple devices. I have been struggling to get flexboxes to display properly across various devices. I am wondering if you could please also help me with a side-by-side flexbox layout? i.e. 2 text boxes aligned neatly side by side without buggy behavior across different devices. And also, if possible, image and text side by side that resize neatly (will add my code above). Thank you so much!